# Raspberry Pi3B is new. I am using it as a companion computer for my ROV together with my FC

Tags: hdmi, ethernet

on my second test while testing the pi with a usb camera, HDMI connected, ethernet cable linked to my laptop and micro USB hooked up for power which is similar to my other ROV setup. On this boot up i got a blank boot up screen. the ethernet port stop blinking green and red led indicator for data and connection. The HDMI was also receiving any signal from the Pi. I took out the memory card, format it and installed the OS accordingly but still nothing on my monitor or ethernet port. However, I do know that the Red led on the Pi board is lighted and the green led is blinking as it should similarly to my other Pi.
Is they some way where I can check on the board with a multimeter to see if maybe I had blown a fuse or something? Its a new Pi which has not been used in my ROV yet.
Thanks

Comment: What power supply are you using? Did it ever work with the hdmi monitor?

Comment: yes it did work with the HDMI before